# (draglist)How to display arraylist value from databases

Tags: android, arraylist, drag-and-drop, android-sqlite

I can insert into databases, but cannot display arraylist value from databases.

Please help me and thanks for your advice.

```
public class DragListActivity extends Activity {                
private static final String CTITLE = "CTITLE"; //cloumn
private static final SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private static List<String> list = null;
private DragListAdapter adapter = null;
Button btn;
DragListView dragListView;
public static List<String> group= new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> navList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private List<String> hashList = new ArrayList<String>();   

private String[] p = new String[] { "'1'", "'2'", "'3'", "'4'", "5'", "'6'", "'7'", "'8'", "'9'", "'10'" };


//  private List<String> moreList = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_list_activity); 



    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm); 

    DragListView dragListView = (DragListView)findViewById(R.id.drag_list); //ListView


    initdata();
    adapter = new DragListAdapter(this, list);
    dragListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(btListner); //button
  }
```

> public Button.OnClickListener btListner=new Button.OnClickListener(){
>
> ```
>               @Override       public void onClick(View v) {       //insert  into database
>
>      SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DB", MODE_PRIVATE,null);   
>      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS direction (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CTITLE TEXT);");   
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(1,"+p[0]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(2,"+p[1]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(3,"+p[2]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(4,"+p[3]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(5,"+p[4]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(6,"+p[5]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(7,"+p[6]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(8,"+p[7]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(9,"+p[8]+");");
>      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO direction (_id, CTITLE) VALUES(10,"+p[9]+");");
>       }
> ```
>
> };

dragviewlist value
How to display value from databases??????

> public void initdata() { //show
>
> ```
>   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
>
>    // ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
>
>       list = new ArrayList<String>();     
>
>        navList.add(p[0]);
>        navList.add(p[1]);
>        navList.add(p[2]);
>        navList.add(p[3]);
>        navList.add(p[4]);
>        navList.add(p[5]);
>        navList.add(p[6]);
>        navList.add(p[7]);
>        navList.add(p[8]);
>        navList.add(null);
>        list.addAll(navList);
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to Query your DB call it fetch(); return a cursor from the function. holding the result set:

```
public void query(){
    Cursor  mCur = dbHelper.fetch(); 

    list = new ArrayList<String>();



    if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String one = (mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Field name")));
     navList.add(one);
                    String two = (mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Field name")));
     navList.add(two);
                    String three = (mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Field name")));
     navList.add(three);


                }while(mCur.moveToNext());

            }

    }
```

Call function query from within a AsyncTask, trigger that AsyncTask from your buttonClick.

Comment: The following code,please download!!
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2juoZFR6Q6IZmo4ZW5sM1I3ZEk&usp=sharing
Thanks your advice and i really need your help Q_Q

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries for databases that will make you job easier.

1. ActiveAndroid: http://www.activeandroid.com/
2. GreenDAO ORM: http://greendao-orm.com/
3. Sprinkles
4. Sugar ORM
5. OrmLite

In case of ActiveAndroid, the code would be just:

```
List<Direction> list = new Select().from(Direction.class).execute();
```